# How can I access current component’s top-level element ref inside a hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to implement a specific mouse over behavior that can be added to any part of the app.

I want this to not create extra nested markup, if that can be avoided at all.

In Angular this can be achieved with something like `<some-component myBehavior="…">`, where I implement a `myBehavior` [attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives).

In React with functional components, the mainstream way to achieve this appears to be with hooks, where I could associate a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) with the top-level element in my component and pass that ref to my hook (`useMyBehavior(mainElRef, …)`).

While it seems to make sense, unfortunately, I’d have to do this with each component that wants this behavior (which could be many). Additionally, if the top-level element is another custom component, getting the ref of the “concrete” underlying DOM element (`div`, `span`, etc.) could involve yet more logic.

All of that is doable, and is better than extra nested markup (which comes with many implications for existing styling), but it’s a lot of effort and extra logic I’d rather avoid if possible. After all, all I need my hook to be aware of is when mouse pointer enters current component’s element’s bounding box.

Hence the question: what’s the most feasible way of letting my hook smartly get a hold of the concrete DOM element that is the top-level wrapper for the current component *without* having to pass it a ref?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no shortcut to getting the `ref` to the top-level DOM element of a component. React Hooks don't "know" in which component they are rendered. And adding this functionality would break one of React's [principles](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components):

> React components hide their implementation details, including their rendered output.

However, you can create and return a `ref` in your hook, so it doesn't need to be passed a `ref`.

```js
function useMyBehavior() {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    function onMouseover(e) {
      // do whatever with ref.current
    }
    ref.current.addEventListener("mouseover", onMouseover);
    return () => ref.current.removeEventListener("mouseover", onMouseover);
  }, [ref.current]);
  return ref;
}

function Component() {
  const ref = useMyBehavior();
  return (
    <NestedComponent ref={ref} prop={"prop"} />
  );
}

const NestedComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {props.prop}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So long as custom components use `React.forwardRef` to forward the ref down to a DOM element, the hook will work. See the docs section on [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Comment: “However, you can create and return a ref in your hook, so it doesn't need to be passed a ref.” — Vital point I have missed. Same is `forwardRef()`, which I haven’t been using yet, and it looks like just the case for it. Huge thanks!

Comment: While looking into forwarded refs, I’ve stumbled across the HOC concept, could make sense under circumstances too

Comment: Something is not right here. I'm getting the warning "The ref value 'ref.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'ref.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function"

Comment: Yes. This works without having `ref.current` in the dependency list of the `useEffect`.